# custom maven archetype: default value for version not used

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

In my maven archetype definition, I would like to set the default version to 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT when the user doesnt enter anything. However, when I create a project based on the archetype, I am always prompted for the version and the default is 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

How do I do this correctly?

I defined a version property in the archetype.properties file and when I compile the archetype, it says the correct version and when I change the value in the archetype.properties, I can see that the console output changes accordingly.

Just on creating a project based on the archetype, I get prompted for the version again.

Thanks for help and tips!

(I'll provide code if necessary)

Comment: whats your archetype-metadata schema?

Comment: and does specifying `-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` not help?

Comment: @nullpointer well I thought that if the user doesnt specify -Dversion then it would use some fallback. Or is -Dversion always mandatory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define custom properties in you archetype metadata. Have a look at the `archetype-metadata.xml` in `META-INF/maven`. For example:

```
my-archetype
|
+ src
  |
  + main
    |
    + resources
      |
      + META-INF
        |
        + maven
          |
          + archetype-metadata.xml
```

A custom property for `version` would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="version">
            <defaultValue>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

More details in [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html).

When you run the `mvn archetype:generate` command referencing an archetype with the above configuration you'll see this in the console output:

```
[INFO] Using property: version = 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Or, if you run the `mvn archetype:generate` command with the parameter `-Dversion=FOO` then you'll see this in the console output:

```
[INFO] Using property: version = FOO
```

Note: this version is, of course, separate from the `archetypeVersion` which defines the version of the archetype itself rather than the version of the module *produced* by the archetype.

Comment: Dont you mean requiredProperties instead of requiredParameters?

Comment: Well, first of all thanks, it works :) However, I did the same thing for groupId and package but it keeps prompting me for those and it uses the groupId of the archetype itself as default value. BUT: in the generated pom, the groupId is shown correctly (I get it form the artifactId by doing a string replace). Any idea what I am still missing?

Comment: If you define a `requiredProperty` without a `defaultValue` then you will be prompted to supply a value for that property. If you define a `requiredProperty` with a `defaultValue` then the default value will be used unless you explicitly supply a value for that property. That's the expected behaviour of `requiredProperties`. Without any more details I'm unable to diagnose your specific issue. You could perhaps raise a question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the more detail you provide the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it... the default value I set is already dynamically generated from another property ({artifactId.replaceAll("-", ".")}) ... thats why I get prompted, because the default value isnt actually generated until velocity runs...right? Or should this be possible?

Comment: Sounds plausible